# Why are square Intergrable functions bounded? How is it related to L2 functions and Hilbert spaces?

Tags: finite-element-method, mathematics

To approximate the weak form of linear elliptic pde to solve Elasticity problem, we use L2 functions and Hilbert space. In that, I read that Square integrable functions are bounded. Why is that true and why boundedness is important here?

Comment: This question sounds very specific to me. You may want to [edit] your question to add more detail so that your question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Could you point to a source saying that L2 functions are bounded? As far as I know, what's bounded is the integral of it's square over the region where they are defined.

Comment: @Zegpi Can you please explain why the integral of its square over the region is bounded?

Comment: @Prashanth That is the definition of a function in L2, any function such that the integral of it's square over the region of support is strictly less that infinity. [Definition from wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function)

Comment: Thank you for the response @Zegpi  ,So any function whose integral of its square over the region is bounded is known as L2 function. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @Prashanth Yes, that is the definition.